# Remove padding on the left and right of a grid system

Tags: html, css

I have a grid system with 10px padding between columns. But i don't want that padding on the left and right side of the whole grid. I have tried putting the columns in a big wrapper and adding margin-left: -10px and margin-right:-10px but it just moves the grid left.

```
<div class="column column-1"><div class="inner"></div></div>
<div class="column column-2"><div class="inner"></div></div> 
<div class="column column-3"><div class="inner"></div></div>
<div class="column column-1"><div class="inner"></div></div>
<div class="column column-1"><div class="inner"></div></div>
<div class="column column-1"><div class="inner"></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.row,
.column {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.column {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
.column-1 {
  width: 33.3333333%;
}
.column-2 {
  width: 66.6666666%;
}
.column-3 {
  width: 100%;
}
.column {
  min-height: 60px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.inner {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  display:block;
  position: relative;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jg137tt6/1/)

Comment: Will those divs be dynamically added or can you separate the rows with another div? (Place rows in their own container)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I notice you have a `.row` class defined in your css, but aren't using it.
If you start using it, and embed your columns within a row, you can use `:first-child` and `:last-child` selectors to change the margins on the end columns.

Like so

```
.row .column:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.row .column:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}

<div class="row">
   <div class="column column-1"><div class="inner"></div></div>
   <div class="column column-2"><div class="inner"></div></div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jg137tt6/2/)

Comment: Awesome thanks! How would you recommend the way I style each column individually, just put another class on the inner of each one?

Comment: Depends on your requirements. But there's nothing stopping you adding more classes directly to the individual columns to add extra styling.